# How to calculate similarity based on purchase records?

Tags: mahout-recommender, bigdata

I have a purchase history data set. It contains userid, itemid, purchase records. The Purchase Records means how many times the user purchased the item.

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gx1rR.png)

So how can I calculate the user or item similarity based on this data set for producing recommendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go for Spark MLlib algorithms. Spark provides the **`Collaborative filtering - Alternating Least Squares (ALS)`** machine learning algorithm which gets trained using the user, products and rating. In your case rating will be the count(Number of times user purchased a item) of purchases for a item.

You can straight away go for the ALS algorithm by following the example shown here [Collaborative filtering - ALS](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-collaborative-filtering.html#collaborative-filtering).

Comment: Thank you so much. I am going to try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cos co-variance and correlation.

https://github.com/Krewn/KPlot/blob/gh-pages/analysisTools.py

Comment: Would you please give me some introduction? Or Java code

Comment: In java I would probably start here, http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6.1/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Mahout has user and item similarity based on the probabilistic Log-Likelihood Ratio (LLR), this has been demonstrated to give superior performance compared to other similarity metrics and is only nominally "similarity", actually a correlation test. LLR in Mahout generates a score for every detected event (line in your dataset) This is collected in an "indicator" matrix with the `spark-itemsimilarity` job. You can use this along with a search engine to create a recommender or use one we created for PredictionIO.

PredictionIO is a machine learning server with DB, workflow control, and storage and compute engine integration. See the [Universal Recommender](http://actionml.com/docs/ur), which uses Mahout on Spark and is a full featured end-to-end recommender that can be queried for item of user-based recommendations.

- http://mahout.apache.org/users/algorithms/intro-cooccurrence-spark.html
- http://actionml.com/docs/ur

Comment: Thanks. I used Log-likelihood ration. But it ignores purchase records. I am thinking if we can improve the recommender system based on purchase records. Because if the user purchased the item more times, it is likely to indicate that the user like the item more.

Comment: You might think that but i've done cross validation experiments using tanimoto which is the primary similarity metric that uses length of vector (number of purchases), cosine (which doesn't use length but does use # of purchases)  and LLR beat both by a large margin. This was on real-world ecom purchase data from a large online retailer. This is because number of purchases often doesn not indicate preference, it indicates something about the product like now long it lasts (deodorant vs. can of red bull ;-).